# How can we prove that this equation cannot be solved?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can we prove that this equation cannot be solved?
$ 25k^3+30k^2+23k+3=x^2$ where x,k are integer numbers

Comment: Consider $k = 1$, $x = \pm 9$. This gives a solution, as $25 + 30 + 23 + 3 = 81 = 9^2 = (-9)^2$

Comment: $k=2,x=\pm 17$ is also OK

Comment: @chenbai ... $25\cdot 2^3+30\cdot 2^2+23\cdot 2+3= 369 \neq \pm 17 ^2$

Comment: I managed to prove some relevant facts, such as 1) $k \equiv 1 \lor 3 \lor 19 \lor 21 \pmod{ 36}$; 2) $x \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$; 3) for $k \gt 1, x \approx 5k\sqrt k$; 4) there is only one solution $(k,x)=(1,9)$ for $k \lt 160.000$

Comment: The recent problem A. 618. from the KöMaL Magazine is this: Prove that the equation $x^3−x+9=5y^2$ has no solution among the integers. The deadline is 10 June. Please do not give him/her any answer or hint.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the equation has an integer solution like a. By direct division of LHS of equation by $(k-a)$we can find that the remainder R is:

$R=23ak +30a^2+25a^3+3-x^2$

$a$ is a solution if $R=0$, that is we must have:

$R=23ak +30a^2+25a^3+3-x^2=0$

Comparing with inital equation we have:

$23ak +30a^2+25a^3=23k +30k^2+25k^3$

Since $23$ is prime to $25$ and $30$ the unique conclusion is:

$k=a=1$ which gives $x= ± 9$

That is except this solution there can be no solutions.